# customized select (css, html) filled by textfile (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have built a select statement in a webpage with css customization - That works without any problems. The complete code also includes one or two parts of js, which still works like a charm.
Now I want to fill the select from a text file (that gets generated by my excel-vb sheet; customer request). I'm not sure where the problem is, but when I try both parts together it doesn't show anything of my html code that's below the select, not even the select itself. The php code is from a helpful post from here and adapted to my case, but I probably forgot something or made a mistake.
Pages are for now all in the same folder.

This is my html and php code:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <select name ="Namen auswählen">
        <option selected="base">Namen auswählen</option>
            <?php
                // define file
                $file = 'test.txt';
                $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
                if ($handle) {
                    while (!feof($handle)) {
                        $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
                        $item = explode('|', $line);
                        echo '<option value="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[0] . '</option>' . "\n";
                                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                                }
            ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my style code:

```
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 30%;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}custom-select  {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.option {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 95%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Edit: This is the js part that actually does the customization.

```
<script>
    var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
    /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    l = x.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        ll = selElmnt.length;
        /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected 
        item:*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
        a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        x[i].appendChild(a);
        /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
        for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
            /*for each option in the original select element, create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
            c = document.createElement("DIV");
            c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
            c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
                and the selected item:*/
                var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
                s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                sl = s.length;
                h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
                for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
                    if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                        s.selectedIndex = i;
                        h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                        y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                        yl = y.length;
                        for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                        }
                        this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                h.click();
            });
            b.appendChild(c);
        }
        x[i].appendChild(b);
        a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
            and open/close the current select box:*/
            e.stopPropagation();
            closeAllSelect(this);
            this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
            this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
    }
    function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
        /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
        except the current select box:*/
        var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
        y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
        xl = x.length;
        yl = y.length;
        for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
            if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                arrNo.push(i)
            } else {
                 y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
            if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
            }
        }
    }
    /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box, then close all select boxes:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
</script>
```

Maybe you have an idea where my mistake is.

KR Vany

Comment: Did you check if you have php errors inside the select request

also $line is inside a loop, so it will be overwritten, and this is not a function so avoid the return

Comment: I checked for general syntax errors as well as theoretical logic, wasn't able to test the php part of the code anywhere though. Any ideas where to check that? I could write a simple statement for the select without css and check if that works, but otherwise no idea.
Also thanks already, I'll remove the return. 
Line should be in a loop, it is supposed to echo the new html line every time before going to the next entry in the file.

Comment: _"it doesn't show anything of my html code that's below the select, not even the select itself."_ - sounds like your script is probably exiting with a fatal error at this point. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enable? If not, go and do that first of all.

Comment: If the list of options is short, try [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) instead of fopen/fgets. Maybe one line is longer than 4kB? I doubt it.. but if both fail you know the file just cannot be read (wrong filename or permissions).

Comment: @CBroe will do that, edit what it tells me and maybe be back :) thanks so much, that actually is a massive help already!

Comment: Found the problem by using the PHP error reporting. Thanks to everyone who helped :)
KR Vany

Comment: @VanyKrümelkeks Would be nice for anyone rading this to know, what the Error was and to mark this as solved